# Velocity variables not set/defined from the parent file

Tags: java, tomcat, velocity

I am using velocity.

**page.html**

```
...
#set($localDecimal='#,##0.00')
#set($localInteger='#,##0')
#set($localNumber='#,##0')
#set($localCurrency=${currentCurrency}+'#,##0.00')
...
#parse('welcome.html')
...
```

**welcome.html**

```
$localNumber
```

I am expecting `#,##0` as oppose to `$localNumber`, it seems that `welcome.html` page is not picking any variables set from `page.html` [*parent template*]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be using `#include` instead of `#parse`.

Include does not do anything, just insert the contents. With Parse, it should work.

See [Include](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#include) and [Parse](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#parse) documentations. It also shows an example how `#parse` is working, the same as your situation.